# Disable internal speakers by default

Tags: sound

I am in an office environment where making sound is not an option. My laptop used to be in mute all the time which is fine.

I have now enabled a SIP account for phone so I need to use the laptop sound. I have paired a bluetooth headset which works fine.

Now I have the following issue: when the bluetooth is disconnected for any reason, the sound is reverted to the internal speakers which is absolutely not what I want.

How can I permanently mute the internal speakers, and make that persistent to anything? I don't want the volume to come back unless I manually revert it. At the moment almost any operation on the sound configuration will re-enable the internal speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Settings > Sound > Line Out > check Mute
[image]

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the headset and put it back?

Comment: Line Out stays on Mute on my desktop.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know what happened ealier then. Thanks!